# EditText inside QuickAction

Tags: android, quickaction

Is it possible to have an EditText control inside a QuickAction?

Any example will be acceptable.

Comment: Or some other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a quick action, i was searching the same thing. But use a custom alertdialog, and put an edittext inside .